# toggle ngClass on respected parent for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular CLI 8.3.0 and i want to make a sidebar with drop-down menu.
I want to toggle "open" class to open the drop-down. the issue i am facing is, when i click to open the drop-down menu, it opens all the drop-down. i just want to open only which is clicked. In addition, i want to close the current drop-down  if i click other menu item to open another drop-down

Here is the component.html

```
<li class="nav__item"
    (click)="toggleShowDiv('divA')"
    >
  <a target="_self">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="ic-corp-setup"></mat-icon>
    <span class="nav__text">Corp setup</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav-sub divA" [@slideInOut]="animationState">
    <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="nav__item"
    (click)="toggleShowDiv('divB')"
    >
  <a target="_self">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="ic-corp-setup"></mat-icon>
    <span class="nav__text">Corp setup</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav-sub divB" [@slideInOut]="animationState">
    <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

my component.ts

```
animationState = 'in';
  toggleShowDiv(divName: string) {
    if (divName === 'divA') {
      console.log(this.animationState);
      this.animationState = this.animationState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
      console.log(this.animationState);
    }
  }
```

animations.ts

```
import {
  trigger, state, style, transition,
  animate, group, query, stagger, keyframes
} from '@angular/animations';

export const SlideInOutAnimation = [
  trigger('slideInOut', [
    state('in', style({
      'max-height': '500px', 'opacity': '1', 'visibility': 'visible'
    })),
    state('out', style({
      'max-height': '0px', 'opacity': '0', 'visibility': 'hidden'
    })),
    transition('in => out', [group([
      animate('400ms ease-in-out', style({
        'opacity': '0'
      })),
      animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({
        'max-height': '0px'
      })),
      animate('700ms ease-in-out', style({
        'visibility': 'hidden'
      }))
    ]
    )]),
    transition('out => in', [group([
      animate('1ms ease-in-out', style({
        'visibility': 'visible'
      })),
      animate('600ms ease-in-out', style({
        'max-height': '500px'
      })),
      animate('800ms ease-in-out', style({
        'opacity': '1'
      }))
    ]
    )])
  ]),
]
```

> i don't need the dependency of classes like "divA" or "divB" because i need to make the menu dynamic.

its not necessary to suggest solution within this boundary. i am open for other approaches. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you could to is to keep track of the **current selected item**.

#### your-component.component.ts

```js
crtSelectedItem: string;

toggleShowDiv (item) {
 // In case you want to be able to open a different menu directly

 if (item === this.crtSelectedItem) {
  // Just a toggle! You clicked on the same item
  this.animationState = this.animationState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out'; 
 } else {
   this.crtSelectedItem = item;
   // Open the new selected item directly
    this.animationState = 'in';
 }
}
```

Then, in your view, you can do something like this.

#### your-component.component.html

```html
<li class="nav__item"
    (click)="toggleShowDiv('divA')"
    >
  <a target="_self">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="ic-corp-setup"></mat-icon>
    <span class="nav__text">Corp setup</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="nav-sub divA" [@slideInOut]="crtSelectedItem === 'divA' ? animationState : 'out'">
    <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

You can follow the same pattern for the other elements.

Comment: not working bro, can we remove the dependency of classes like "divA" and "divB"? check my edited question.

Comment: Assuming that you'd have a `*ngFor` and each item has an `id`, you can only keep track of the id of the item. Then, in your template you can check based on the id. The gist here, in my opinion, is to keep track of the current selected element so you can only perform certain actions only on that specific item. Yes, you can change them. All the configuration should be in your items array.

Comment: i tried your solution and its working. upvote :)  one more thing, is it possible to close current open menu if i click on other menu item to open drop-down menu? right now, if i click on other menu item to open drop-down, it only closes the drop-down which is already open and i have to click again to open another drop-down.

Comment: Glad it worked! Hmm, I think you should reset the `animationState` if an element with a **different id** is selected. I have updated my answer. Let me know if it works!